# in pythonanywhere.com the up arrow gives ^[[A

Tags: pythonanywhere

The bash console was working fine in the morning. In the after, the up arrow started giving ^[[A. How is this fixed?

Not educated enough to try. Checked the net and nobody said how fix it.

Comment: Did you try reloading the console in the browser?  Which browser and OS are you using?

Comment: I did. I was in chrome with windows 11. I switched to firefox and the Bash console works there.